# Find connected components in a graph of computer network with parallel pairwise tests

Tags: computer-networks, connected-components

I have N nodes, a node might have an undirected edge to other nodes, resulting in K connected components (K<=N, K unknown).
I can test if a given pair is connected. In each step in time, I can run N/2 such tests *in parallel* (a given node can be tested once per step).  Each connected component is a cluster graph (it has no three-vertex induced path).
The goal is to find all K components and list of nodes per component.

The actual application is nodes in a computer network, therefore I can run pairwise tests in parallel. I have ~256 nodes. How to approach this? A naive solution of N*(N-1)/2 tests  is too costly. Hopefully I could reuse a library algorithm in Python a solution.

For example for detecting the graph below (7 nodes, 3 connected-components (CC)), I might need this set of tests:

```
Step1 tests: D-A, C-F, E-B
Step2 tests: A-B, C-B, D-E (found CC: A-B-C)
Step3 tests: D-F (Found CC: D)
Step4 tests: E-F (Found CC: E-F)
Done.
```

[image: graph example]

Comment: Do you have any way to list the neighbors of an edge or do anything than test if a given pair of nodes are connected?  If not, the best you can do is about N steps where in each step you test N/2 pairs, as you'll need to test essentially every possible pair.

Comment: I can test if a given pair is connected. In each step in time, I can run N/2 such  tests (a node can be tested once per step).

Answer (score 1):

The best you can do is about $N$ steps.

You can do it in about $N$ steps, by just testing $N/2$ new pairs in each step, until you've tested all pairs.  Then once you have tested all pairs, you can use any standard algorithm to compute connected components (e.g., depth-first search).

You can't do better.  In the worst case, you have to inspect essentially every pair of nodes, so you'll need to have inspected about $N^2/2$ pairs.  (If there is even a single pair $u,v$ that you haven't inspected, where there is no other path of length $>1$ from $u$ to $v$, then you can't tell whether $u,v$ are in the same component or not without querying the $u,v$ pair.)   Since you can only inspect $N/2$ pairs per step, you'll need at least $N$ steps.

Comment: Thx! I should have stated clearly: each component is a cluster graph (it has no three-vertex induced path). Does that help reduce the complexity? e.g., I could tell if , are in  the same component, if I've tested both with some vertex m.

Comment: @GiliNachum, yup, that's a critical detail.  Sounds worth asking as a separate question.  I also recommend stating whether you care about constant factors, and listing the best strategy you know.  I expect it'll still take $\ge cN$ steps for some constant $c>0$.